# Some Truffle tests not running after truffle init (Mac OSX) Uncaught TypeError

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

I am trying to build a DApp using Truffle. I have installed Testrpc and Truffle globally with NPM. I ran testrpc in a terminal window and ran truffle test. I get 2 passing and 3 failing tests. The three failing tests are:

```
TestMetacoin testInitialBalanceUsingDeployedContract:

TestMetacoin testInitialBalanceWithNewMetaCoin:
```

and

```
Contract: MetaCoin should send coin correctly:
```

each is failing with the same message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ethjs-abi/lib/index.js:139:34
  at Array.map (native)
  at Object.decodeEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ethjs-abi/lib/index.js:138:6)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:73:38
  at Array.map (native)
  at Object.decodeLogs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:44:19)
  at Object.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:172:35)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:142:25
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:89:9
  at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:119:13)
  at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
  at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
  at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
```

I am sure I am missing something simple, any help is appreciated.

Edit:  So it looks like for some reason in the decodeEvent method is getting nil for topics in the failing tests.  This is my first experience with truffle or daps so I am not really sure how to remedy this but I will keep digging.

Comment: Hi Ruby. I'm not sure this is on point, but suggest trying $ truffle migrate --reset, then test again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I did that with the same result.  the tests are hitting the testrpc instance I am running as I can see transactions being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a bug in truffle.  I had to uninstall and reinstall truffle and my tests are all green now.  https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/377